# Multiple SQL Table Errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create multiple tables and receive different errors:
I receive the no right parenthesis error on some of the tables as well as only 1 primary key per table.

```
CREATE TABLE GAMER 
(
    USERNAME                 VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY ,
    PASSWORD_password        VARCHAR(255) ,
    FIRSTNAME                VARCHAR(255) ,
    LASTNAME                 VARCHAR(255) ,
    EMAIL                    VARCHAR(255) 
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_character 
(
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(150) PRIMARY KEY ,
    LEVEL_level             INT(150) ,  
    EXP_exp                 INT(1250) ,
    HP                      INT(1250) ,
    MP                      INT(1250) ,
    STRENGTH                INT(1250) ,
    INTILLIGENCE            INT(1250) ,
    DEXTERITY               INT(1250) ,
    CLASS_class             VARCHAR(150) ,
    USERNAME                VARCHAR(150) , 

    CONSTRAINT username_fk  FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES GAMER
); 

CREATE TABLE PVP_MATCH 
( 
    MATCHID                 INT(15) PRIMARY KEY ,
    WINNER_NAME             VARCHAR(150),
    LOSER_NAME              VARCHAR(150) , 
    KILL_TIME               INT(2000) , 
    KILL_SCORE              INT(2000) , 

    CONSTRAINT WINNER_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (WINNER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character(CHARACTER_NAME) , 
    CONSTRAINT LOSER_NAME_fk  FOREIGN KEY (LOSER_NAME)  REFERENCES CHARACTER_character(CHARACTER_NAME)
); 

CREATE TABLE GUILD 
(
    GUILD_NAME              VARCHAR(150)PRIMARY KEY ,
    FOUNDING_TIME           VARCHAR(1500) ,
    STATUS                  VARCHAR(1500) 
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_GUILD 
(
    GUILD_NAME              VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY , 

    CONSTRAINT GUILD_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (GUILD_NAME) REFERENCES GUILD(GUILD_NAME)  , 
    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (CHARACTER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character(CHARACTER_NAME)
); 

CREATE TABLE ITEM 
(
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY , 
    VALUE_value             INT(1500) , 
    STATUS                  VARCHAR(1500) ,
    TYPE_type               INT(1500) 
); 

CREATE TABLE ARMOR 
(
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY , 
    DEFENSE                 INT(1500) , 
    TYPE_type               INT(1500) , 

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEM_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE ACCESSORY (

    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    SPECIAL_EFFECTS         VARCHAR(1500) , 
    TYPE_type               VARCHAR(1500) , 

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEM_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE WEAPON ( 
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    SPEED                   INT(1500) , 
    DPS                     INT(1500) , 

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEM_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_ITEM 
( 
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY, 
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY, 

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEM_NAME) , 
    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (CHARACTER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character
); 

CREATE TABLE SKILL 
( 
    SKILL_ID                INT(1500) PRIMARY KEY, 
    NAME_name               VARCHAR(1500) , 
    MPCOST                  INT(1500) , 
    LEVEL_level             INT(1500) , 
    DESCRIPTION             VARCHAR(1500) 
); 

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_SKILL 
( 
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY , 
    SKILL_ID                INT(1500) PRIMARY KEY, 

    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY CHARACTER_NAME REFERENCES CHARACTER_character(CHARACTER_NAME)  , 
    CONSTRAINT SKILL_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY SKILL_ID REFERENCES SKILL(SKILL_ID)
); 

CREATE TABLE PREREQUISITE_SKILL 
(
    SKILL_ID                INT(1500) PRIMARY KEY , 
    PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID   VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY , 

    CONSTRAINT SKILL_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY SKILL_ID REFERENCES SKILL(SKILL_ID) , 
    CONSTRAINT PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID) REFERENCES SKILL(SKILL_ID)
);
```

I have tried just to run something as simple as this:

```
CREATE TABLE GUILD 
(
    GUILD_NAME              VARCHAR(150)PRIMARY KEY ,
    FOUNDING_TIME           VARCHAR(1500) ,
    STATUS                  VARCHAR(1500) 
);
```

But I receive the no right parenthesis error. The format seems correct.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Gamer Table: name is already used by an existing object, Character: missing right parenthsis , pvp match: missing right paren, guild: name is already used by existing object, characterguild: table can only have one primary, item: missing right paren, armor: missing right paren, accessory: name is already in use by existing obj, weapon:  missing right paren, character_item: only one primary, skill: missing right paren, character_skill: missing right paren, and prereqskill: missing right paren

Comment: The first error you give, `name is already used by an existing object`, is a name collision; it's telling you that you've already created the table. The `missing right parenthesis` errors are, I believe, because you have to specify column names when you're adding foreign key constraints. So, instead of `CONSTRAINT username_fk  FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES GAMER` you would have `CONSTRAINT username_fk  FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES GAMER(USERNAME)`

Comment: Updated my current code. Still getting the same errors with those changes(right paren)

Comment: @user3478868 Your example at the end runs fine on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74362), what Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Unrelated but: there is no hidden optimization done for a varchar length of 255. It's just as "good" as 200 or 345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several errors: the INT type doesn't take any width parameter (number can do though), composite primary keys needs to be declared as constraints, and there were several name clashes. Also, in the last table the data type for `PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID` was declared as `VARCHAR(1500)`, but it looks like it should be `INT`as it references a field declared as `INT`in the `SKILL` table.

Fixed it for you: see sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e164) for proof (using Oracle 11G R2).

```
CREATE TABLE GAMER
(
    USERNAME                 VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY ,
    PASSWORD_password        VARCHAR(255) ,
    FIRSTNAME                VARCHAR(255) ,
    LASTNAME                 VARCHAR(255) ,
    EMAIL                    VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_character
(
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(150) PRIMARY KEY ,
    LEVEL_level             INT ,
    EXP_exp                 INT ,
    HP                      INT ,
    MP                      INT ,
    STRENGTH                INT ,
    INTILLIGENCE            INT ,
    DEXTERITY               INT ,
    CLASS_class             VARCHAR(150) ,
    USERNAME                VARCHAR(150) ,

    CONSTRAINT username_fk  FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES GAMER
);

CREATE TABLE PVP_MATCH
(
    MATCHID                 INT PRIMARY KEY ,
    WINNER_NAME             VARCHAR(150),
    LOSER_NAME              VARCHAR(150) ,
    KILL_TIME               INT ,
    KILL_SCORE              INT ,

    CONSTRAINT WINNER_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (WINNER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character ,
    CONSTRAINT LOSER_NAME_fk  FOREIGN KEY (LOSER_NAME)  REFERENCES CHARACTER_character
);

CREATE TABLE GUILD
(
    GUILD_NAME              VARCHAR(150)PRIMARY KEY ,
    FOUNDING_TIME           VARCHAR(1500) ,
    STATUS                  VARCHAR(1500)
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_GUILD
(
    GUILD_NAME              VARCHAR(1500),
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(1500),

    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_GUILD_PK PRIMARY KEY (GUILD_NAME, CHARACTER_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT GUILD_NAME_fk3 FOREIGN KEY (GUILD_NAME) REFERENCES GUILD ,
    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_NAME_fk4 FOREIGN KEY (CHARACTER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character
);

CREATE TABLE ITEM
(
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    VALUE_value             INT ,
    STATUS                  VARCHAR(1500) ,
    TYPE_type               INT
);

CREATE TABLE ARMOR
(
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    DEFENSE                 INT ,
    TYPE_type               INT ,

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM
);

CREATE TABLE ACCESSORY (

    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    SPECIAL_EFFECTS         VARCHAR(1500) ,
    TYPE_type               VARCHAR(1500) ,

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk4 FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM
);

CREATE TABLE WEAPON (
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500) PRIMARY KEY ,
    SPEED                   INT ,
    DPS                     INT ,

    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_ITEM
(
    CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(1500),
    ITEM_NAME               VARCHAR(1500),

    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_ITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHARACTER_NAME, ITEM_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT ITEM_NAME_fk3 FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_NAME) REFERENCES ITEM ,
    CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_NAME_fk FOREIGN KEY (CHARACTER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character
);

CREATE TABLE SKILL
(
    SKILL_ID                INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME_name               VARCHAR(1500) ,
    MPCOST                  INT ,
    LEVEL_level             INT ,
    DESCRIPTION             VARCHAR(1500)
);

CREATE TABLE CHARACTER_SKILL
(
  CHARACTER_NAME          VARCHAR(1500),
  SKILL_ID                INT,

  CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_SKILL_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHARACTER_NAME, SKILL_ID),
  CONSTRAINT CHARACTER_NAME_fk34 FOREIGN KEY (CHARACTER_NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTER_character ,
  CONSTRAINT SKILL_ID_f1k FOREIGN KEY (SKILL_ID) REFERENCES SKILL
);

  CREATE TABLE PREREQUISITE_SKILL
(
  SKILL_ID                INT,
  PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID   INT,
  CONSTRAINT PREREQUISITE_SKILL_PK PRIMARY KEY (SKILL_ID, PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID),
  CONSTRAINT SKILL_ID_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (SKILL_ID) REFERENCES SKILL,
  CONSTRAINT PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (PREREQUISITE_SKILL_ID) REFERENCES SKILL(SKILL_ID)
);
```

I didn't put any thought into solving the constraint name clashes, but just added random numbers. You can surely improve them.

Comment: Ran the code and I understand what you fixed. Some of the tables executed no problem but the error the character_character table is giving is theres no primary key for the gamer reference table when the primary key in that table is username. I added(USERNAME) next to the references gamer but it gives me no matching unique or primary key for this column list.

Comment: @user3478868 The issue might be that the width of the USERNAME fields are different in GAMER and CHARACTER_character, try making them the same size. It does run without error in the SQL Fiddle though.

Comment: Which is weird because im running the same version of oracle that sql fiddle has selected and I get errors on aqua data through oracle but not sql fiddle

Comment: @user3478868 That is odd; I don't use Aqua myself so I couldn't tell you what might be the remaining issue. The script should work ok now though.

Comment: I got it to work. Your code ran perfectly thank you!

Comment: @user3478868 Good to hear :)